# transformersからTFGPT2LMHeadModelをインポートできない (cannot import name 'TFGPT2LMHeadModel' from 'transformers')

Tags: python, 機械学習, 自然言語処理, google-colaboratory

[Huggingface Transformers 入門 (6) - テキスト生成](https://note.com/npaka/n/n5d296d8ae26d)

こちらの記事を真似てコードを動かしていますが、最初の

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
```

で以下のエラーが出ます

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4d671ac52c7c> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
      3 
      4 
      5 tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")

ImportError: cannot import name 'TFGPT2LMHeadModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)
```

色々調べて、tensoeflow==2.0.1を入れてみたのですが、動きませんでした。

ライブラリが古くて更新されているのでしょうか？
環境はGoogle ColabのGPUを利用してtensorflowのバージョンを変更した以外はすべて同じとなっています。

詳しい方原因を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: Windows10のjupyterやipythonではないローカルな環境ではimport出来ました。何か環境問題でしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同様の報告がバグとして報告され、installationの記事が追加されたようです。
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3396

> This repository is tested on Python 3.6+, PyTorch 1.0.0+ (PyTorch 1.3.1+ for examples) and TensorFlow 2.0.

> You should install  Transformers in a virtual environment. If you're unfamiliar with Python virtual environments, check out the user guide.

とあり、ほかの影響を受けない仮想環境に導入するように記載があります。
実際いろいろがさがさと入っている私の環境では同様のエラーとなり、py venvで作った環境では問題なくimportできました。　情報共有まで。。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。私も個人的に環境作成して動かしてみます。